# Calculating difference between two dates in rails activerecord select statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Placements model, which contains check_in and check_out date columns, as well as an integer field 'places'. I'm trying to write a query (postgres) which calculates the total 'person-nights' for a user. A User has many Placements through Listings, so for each placement, I need to find the difference between the check_out and check_in dates in days, and multiply this by the number of places in that placement. Ideally I can do this in one query, something along the lines of the following logic:

```
  hosted_personnights_count = current_user.hosted_placements
    .select("SUM((placements.check_out - placements.check_in)*placements.people) as datediff")
    .where("placements.confirmed_at IS NOT NULL and placements.check_out < ?", Date.today)
    .group(:user_id)
```

Obviously this isn't the right syntax, but I thought it was easier to explain this way than try to list all the postgres functions I've tried that don't work. Any ideas? Placements table looks something like:

```
    create_table "placements", force: true do |t|
     t.integer  "user_id"
     t.integer  "listing_id"
     t.date     "check_in"
     t.date     "check_out"
     t.integer  "people"
     t.datetime "confirmed_at"
     t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    end
```

Comment: Could you describe the `placements` table? If `check_in` & `check_out` fields are really `date`s (and not `timestamp`s) then the difference will yield an integer (in days), so your query could work as it is.

Comment: Yes they are dates, not datetimes, have added the placements table above. I'll try it as you suggested, fingers crossed

Comment: its almost there, just giving me the "must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" error, so I just need to get the grouping right (this error has confused me in the past). Ideally it needs to spit out a single value rather than an array of placements.

Comment: That is because you also select columns other than the `SUM(...) as datediff` -- btw if you need a single value, you dont have to use `GROUP BY user_id`, instead you could use `WHERE user_id = ?`

Comment: but I need to SUM(check_in-check_out*places) so I can get a single value for the total person-nights hosted for that user. Theres already a WHERE user_id = , since I'm using current_user.hosted_placements. So what do I need to group by to avoid that error? Experimenting now but still no luck

Comment: you could maybe post it as a solution so at least you get the credit :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is simple as

```
SELECT SUM((check_out - check_in) * people) AS all
  FROM placements
 WHERE confirmed_at IS NOT NULL
   AND check_out < ?
   AND user_id = ?
```

You don't need a `GROUP BY` clause, if you want to sum it *all* up.

And make sure you don't accidentally select another column (after `all`).

Comment: I think its on the right track, but my query without the group still gives the following in my rails log (note that the inner join comes from the association current_user.hosted_placements): SELECT SUM((check_out - check_in)*people) as all FROM "placements" INNER JOIN "listings" ON "placements"."listing_id" = "listings"."id" WHERE "listings"."user_id" = $1 AND (confirmed_at IS NOT NULL and check_out < '2014-07-05') [["user_id", 5]]
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "placements.check_in" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Just checked and I get the same error if I just use your query without the inner join - SELECT SUM((check_out - check_in)*people) as all FROM "placements" WHERE (confirmed_at IS NOT NULL and check_out < '2014-07-05')

Comment: Got it, turns out activerecord was putting an ORDER in there, which was requiring that column to be in the select. The working query is current_user.hosted_placements.where("confirmed_at IS NOT NULL and check_out < ?", Date.today).sum("(check_out - check_in)*people")